# Is there any modern scalable way to do system call monitoring?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, kernel, ubuntu-18.04

I wrote a kernel module to replace the Linux kernel service routines (e.g. system calls) with security-enforcing code, similar to SELinux or AppArmor, with the main exceptions of ruleset control on-the-fly and big data integration.

Security-wise, The only way to use the OS services from an application is via my supervision code, which is protected by the kernel's native ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) and is read-only.

Since the code and the system calls are marked read-only, they can only be bypassed by another kernel module, which cannot be loaded without approval under most exploit scenarios.

The kernel module communicates MongoDB, sends logs and receives rules on-the-fly.

The result is that every OS service such as disk/file access is logged and can be stopped if a block rule applies.

The code inherits GPL license from the kernel so similar products should probably be GPL too.

Is there any scalable way to achieve this result as described above?

```
{
 "process": "cat",
 "pid": 14975,
 "accessed file": "/etc/passwd",
 "user id": 1000
}
```

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic on serverfault.

Comment: It's not a recommendation, it's a technology question, asking if such product exists prior to investing my time in further development.

Comment: Well, I would disagree, but since I don't have the rep to vote to close here my opinion has no real bearing.

Comment: I'm sure if there's a problem a moderator would address it.

Comment: I do not see a lot of differences with SELinux, so you will need to explain more.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Mostly centralized shareable ruleset control on-the-fly via async big data integration, Also the implementation is via syscall wrapping LKM in real-time and not pre-compilation kernel code.

Comment: Besides "big data" that I think is very irrelevant in that context; all the rest is done by SELinux AFAIK. Also are you speaking about some runnig code you created or is this just an idea on the design table currently? At the end of the day I am not sure to understand what your question is in fact...

Comment: The code I built works, and i built it to overcome the scale management problem and the ability to control multiple (1000's) servers from a central location. I'm looking for similar products. Another problem I'm trying to solve is the 'history' tracking of a process accessing network for example, who touched it, where it came from, etc.